# CORS in .net Core application isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have .Net Core application with angular 2 cli. I am trying to call my controller action from the different port, I know that I can use CORS to make that work, but it is not working. has anyone the idea what could be the problem? thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You allow https but your app is running on http...
Your configured policy is not used, you should do this differenty see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#set-the-allowed-origins

Comment: Post code not pictures !

Answer (score 0):

Your current configuration is allowing the wrong origin (HTTPS and not HTTP).

```
//Optional - called before the Configure method by the runtime
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{    
    app.UseCors(builder =>
       {
           builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
       });
   )
}
```